# How to deactivate an app once in production - can code be added?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, debugging, google-play

After a tiring 3.5 months I learned how to build and launch an app using Flutter and Android Studio. I tested in debug mode on various emulators and all worked well.

I then built the app bundle and uploaded on to Google Play Store as an internal release - again everything ran well.

I pushed this in to Production. After a week of waiting for a review, the app launched. I uninstalled the test version and installed the live production version - and that's when the problems started. The app began to crash in places it hadn't before. Namely on certain pages (and often after the render of certain pages the app closes after c.3 seconds) or upon button presses on certain pages.

I have now added Crashlytics to the app (which I didn't have before), and have pushed this as a second version on to the Google Play Store - and again it's pending review. The questions I have are:

1. Can I deactivate an app once it's live on the app store to prevent any more downloads? - Is there any code that can be added to the app to do this internally? I can not see any options or instructions within the Play Store. It seems a little crazy that I now know my app has 'bugs' which never materalised in test, but i can't 'switch it off'?
2. I have only been able to add Crashlytics this time for a new production release, and once installed and I can try and work out what the problem is with error logs. Once I have I will have to create a third version and again add as a new release and wait for Google to approve - is this really the most efficient way?
3. Why would or could a Production release of an app crash when the Debug version, or Production release version in Internal Test mode, did not? - I find it so strange that I have so many tools available and yet none detected a problem until launch

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you can unpublish your app from playstore
   goto console>select your app>setup>advanced setting>unpublish app
   this will stop your app from appearing to new users and getting new download from
   playstore

2.fixing bugs always need a new release to update your app there is no way to get around
uploading a new release and waiting for the review to end (this is for production app)

3.your testing might not have encountered any bugs because you might be testing on one
device or emulator with a specific api for example api 30 ,and the bugs are being
detected on other apis or device properties you haven't covered in your testing

Comment: 1 Thanks for that, I didn't see this option ...... 2. OK thanks ..... 3. It's the exact same device I used. Even now if I connect the device to Android Studio and run the app it works fine, if I then uninstall the app and download the version from Google Play it crashes on the same device. I even created a new appbundle, uploaded it as a version 1.0.1 - and again it crashes, yet I run the same build from Android Studio and works fine! It's soul destroying!

Comment: may i ask what exactly is crashing in the app since some functions need some changes in code from debug to production which may cause the app working in debug but crashes when you download it from the playstore

Comment: It's a little difficult to tell. Some buttons when pressed cause the app to crash, and although some pages load ok, after a few seconds the app just crashes. Always the same buttons and same pages - but each page that crashes has a few thousands lines of code, so very difficult to see. I'm trying to install Crashlytics but having issues there too!